# Continue script execution after exec in bash

Tags: bash, authentication, ubuntu-14.04, environment

I have such code:

```
echo 'test'
usr=$USER
sudo sh -c "exec su $usr"
echo 'test1'
```

And for example `echo 'test'` is code where I configuring something that requirs me to relogin in new shell. But then where code is `echo 'test1'` I need to continue configuring using reloaded new shell.

Is there way to do that automatically? Like start new shell in parallel or something like that?

Ubuntu 14.04, bash.

Update:

For example, I need to install virsh but after installation it requires sudo to run. My script configurs groups adding $USER to the libvirtd group. Then I need to relogin. I can do that with `sudo sh -c "exec su $usr"`. After that I need the script to continue execution. Is there way to do that?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Can you please provide more explanation?

Comment: Hi. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change with `visudo` your sudoers configuration so that you are no longer asked for a password. See `man visudo` and `man sudoers`.

I suggest to use a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
echo 'test'
usr="$USER"
sudo su - "$USER" << EOF
echo 'test1'
EOF
```

Comment: Seems to be working. So echo 'test1' will be executed in new subshell? But I think I need to change current shell with command like sudo sh -c "exec su $usr" to update environment. Please see my update in question.